# Max Client Bandwidth

Tags: bandwidth, multiplayer

I am making a small Online 2D RPG multiplayer game that uses a client-server architecture.  I was reading up on the max bandwidth a client can receive from the server for I don't just kill players' connections, but am having a hard time finding real good data on google.

Currently updating the status of a player on screen takes 29bytes.  I send an update every 100 ms, so that's about 300 bytes per second per player.  I read that the Valve Source engine targets only 5-7KB/s.  Whats a good safe limit I should shoot for, for I can catch all but the lowest bandwidth users.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, 5 KB/s is 40 kilobits/second. 0.3kb/sec should be perfectly fine. Anyone still on dialup is going to be getting 56kb/sec (7KB/sec), and there aren't many people on dialup playing multiplayer games I'd imagine.

Comment: well,29 bytes * 10 = 300 bytes, not bits, sorry for confusion, editing post :)

Comment: People don't automatically get 56k baud connections on dialup... 19.2k is still a common connection in some telephone exchanges.  This doesn't change your bottom-line, but it's worth mentioning

Comment: As I said, I can't imagine many of those are playing multiplayer games.

Comment: As I said, it doesn't change the bottom-line of your answer